# Flyway can not find resources in weblogic Java EE 7 deployment

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c, flyway

Before I ask my question I better say that I am working on a corporate laptop with no admin rights. Most of the software I needed came from old software packages prepared within the company that contain a mix of useful and obsolete software, so the environment is a little bit messed up and a collaegue of mine didn't have the same problems on his laptop.

I am using Weblogic 12.2.2.1 (at least this one comes from a clean installer) with java 8 update 65.

I have an ear file containing at the root level a jar file with some resources and a war file with a web application and all the dependencies. The application is supposed to work in a Java EE 7 environment. When I deployed it locally I checked the classpath with the JDK tools and I could only see the basic java and weblogic libraries, then I checked the classpath with the Classloader Analysis Tool and I saw that the jar at the root level of the earfile was loaded by the weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader while all the content of the war file was loaded by the weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader
This separation had an impact, because at startup Flyway tries to load the migration scripts as classpath resources and it fails. I debugged it and I saw that it runs from the GenericClassLoader and that classloader can't see those resources.

My first question is why the GenericClassLoader can't find the resources, shouldn't it check also the resources held by the other classloaders up in the inheritance chain?
But then, is it more a Weblogic issue, a Flyway issue or a setup issue?

May I expect the same problems in the future from other third party libraries searching for some resources?

As a workaround I moved the scripts to the war file, is there a cleaner solution?

Additional note, I tried both staged and non staged deployments.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary jar files in the root of an EAR file are not accessible to any other modules without additional configuration, such as the addition of a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file containing a `Class-Path` entry in your web module.

An easier alternative to this is to place your resources jar in the `lib` directory of your EAR file. Jars in this directory are automatically made visible to all other modules in the EAR:

```
myApp.ear
 \-META-INF
   \-application.xml
 \-myWebApp.war
 \-lib
   \-resources.jar
```